# Unable to bind data to the razor view even though the model is not null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding

Even though the model is not null the required html is not rendered. This is my razor view:

```
@model List<Product>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Cart";
}

@for(int i=0;i<=Model.Count()-1;i++)
{
    <p>foreach triggered</p>
    var image = "~/images/" + Model[i].product_image_path;
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <img src="@image" alt="No image" class="img-fluid" width="60" asp-append-version="true" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <p class="justify-content-md-start">@Model[i].ProductName</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <p>₹@Model[i].Price</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                     @*change quantity button*@
                <div class="input-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light"> - </button>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="@Model[i].Quantity" readonly />
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light"> + </button>
                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />       
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                           <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" id="button-minus">Remove</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Here is my `get` action method. This is basically retrieving the product from the models. I am returning an object of `List<Product>`. Trying to loop over it using for loop on razor view does not seem to work.

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Cart() 
{
    var model = new CartProductViewModel();
    var sessionId = HttpContext.Session.Id;
    var allCartItems = context.cartItems;
    var allProducts = context.products;

    var currentCartItem = allCartItems.Where(p => p.Product.ProductId.Equals(sessionId)).Select(p=>p).ToList();
    List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
    foreach (var item in currentCartItem) 
    {
        var id = item.Product.ProductId;
        if (id is null) { return View("NotFound"); }
        Product prod = allProducts.Where(p => p.ProductId.Equals(id)).Select(p=>p).Single();
        products.Add(prod);
    }           
    return View(products);
}
```

Comment: Can you share the data of `products`?

Comment: Do you mean the model class?

Comment: I mean the data in `List<Product> products`.

Comment: @AbdullahKhan: Try to use `FirstOrDefault()` instead of `First()`, because the `First()` will trough  the `System.InvalidOperationException` exception if the source sequence is empty. See examples here: [https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/querying-entity-graph-in-entity-framework.aspx](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/querying-entity-graph-in-entity-framework.aspx)